# Angular - Optmize mat-expansion-panel ngFor

Tags: angular

I have the following code to fill a mat-accordion with mat-expansion-panels:

```
<mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByFunction; let i = index" hideToggle="true">
        <!-- item details here -->
        </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing  with the right tool:

I want to show about 435 items in this mat-accordion. When the user clicks in one of then, it will expand and will show the item details.

But, when assigning the values of "items" array, it hangs the browser tab for about 6 seconds, and I would like that this doesn't happen.

I don't know if 435 items its too much for this occassion, because I already worked with more than 2.000 records in a page without this browser tab hang issue (please, don't blame me, the system user demanded to see all these 2.000 records in a page :( )

Is there a way to solve this hang issue or should I use mat-table instead?

I tried to use the expansion panel because it seems very fancy to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Does it already hang if you have 435 expansion panels which are empty or is there content inside? If there is content inside, you can try using [lazy rendering](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#lazy-rendering).

If the problem is simply the number of expansion panels, you can try to use expansion panel without accordion and instead try rendering the list with [virtual scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling).

Comment: Hi, they have content inside. I tried to use the lazy rendering with ng-template example, it improves, but didn't fully solved the problem.

I will try with virtual scrolling and I will tell you the results